# contraction of annex is to annex's

Tags: contractions

If I want to say the annex is soon to be hijacked, can I use a contraction:

The annex's soon to be hijacked

thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good idea. There are three s-sounds in a row there. A little bit of vowel can't hurt. And it's not a common thing to say or write. Why try to save a space there?

Comment: In spoken English, *the annex's soon to be hijacked* sounds exactly like *the annex is soon to be hijacked*, so there is no reason to fashion a stilted contraction in writing.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, because *is* in that sentence can't be shortened to a schwa (which is what would happen with a **possessive** *annex's*).

Contrast with something like "Where is the cat?" in which *is* can be shortened and for which *Where's* is quite acceptable.